# Web and database servers are starting but EasyPHP Dashbord is not recognizing it

Tags: easyphp

In EasyPHP 16.1.1 dashbord when I click on start, Apache and MySQL are starting but the dashbord interface is not recognizing it. The dashboard is still proposing me to launch the servers (but on a different port this time).

I checked and both servers are running, I can access the www folder through localhost.
Nothing special in the log files.

Install : EasyPHP 16.1.1 on a Windows 8.1 x64

If someone has an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

- Open the task manager and the processes eds-* if any
- Delete the files *conf_last_dbserver.php* and *conf_last_dbserver.php* in *eds-dashboard*
- Run *run-easyphp-devserver.exe* again
- Open the Administration
- Restart your servers

Comment: Thank's @EasyPHP for your answer but there is no conf_last_* php files in the eds-dashboard folder and your solution doesn't help with my issue.